# Cannot add SendGrid resource from Azure Portal

Tags: azure, sendgrid

I'm trying to add the SendGrid SaaS resource from Azure Marketplace.

Following error occurs, when it's start deploying:

```
{
    "status": "Failed",
    "error": {
        "code": "GatewayAuthenticationFailed",
        "message": "Gateway authentication failed for 'https://rp.prod.marketplacesaas.azure.com/'. Diagnostic information: timestamp '20210826T155832Z', tracking id 'b1de8474-c6a9-46a7-bf5c-d926396f168e', request correlation id 'd4579a7f-aa6b-473d-9189-b9a101b97c10'."
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot here]

It's the first SendGrid subscription in this azure subscription.
I'm trying to add this as an azure subscription owner.
No special policies were set.
I've tried do the same on newly created azure subscription, and everything was fine.

Does anyone know where to dig?

Comment: I would take this up with Azure support to see why you can't add this resource, especially if you can in other subscriptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error was resolved after a month, when subscription expired on SendGrid side, then it could be successfully provisioned from Azure again. So time heals in this case.